# Eloquent way of filtering on foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Product model that has many SalePrices (as they change over time), stored in two database tables linked through a foreign key and eloquent relationship:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

  public function sale_prices()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\SalePrices');
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is filter Products based on an incoming Http request query, so I get the list of products in my controller:

```
$products = Product::whereIn('type', $request->types)->where('active', 1);
```

And then, I check for a minimum price or a maximum price, and try to filter accordingly:

```
if ($request->has('min_price')) {
    $products->sale_prices()->where('price', '>=', $request->min_price);
}

if ($request->has('max_price')) {
    $products->sale_prices()->where('price', '<=', $request->max_price);
}

 $products = $products->get();
```

This is not working, and is giving me this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sale_prices()
```

I understand that the $products variable is now a collection of items, but I'm not sure how to apply my filter on these. I can loop through them, but how will I apply the where clause that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sale_prices()` is a method of Model object, you cannot call it by Eloquent builder.

Use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to check which product has relationship with min_price or max_price.

```php
$products = Product::whereIn('type', $request->types)->where('active', 1);

if ($request->has('min_price')) {
    $products->whereHas('sale_prices', function($query) use ($min_price) {
        $query->where('price', '>=', $min_price);
    });
}

if ($request->has('max_price')) {
    $products->whereHas('sale_prices', function($query) use ($max_price) {
        $query->where('price', '<=', $max_price);
    });
}
$products->whereIn('type', $request->types)->where('active', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Does it matter if the "whereIn" is added in the final call to get or can I just to "$products = $products->get();"?

Comment: @CornelVerster u'r welcome. If you add `whereIn` after `get`, it is using collection method `whereIn`, if you apply `whereIn` before `get()`, it is using eloquent-builder whereIn method, It is diff, Although the result is same,I still recommend use `whereIn` before `get()`, because it will execute in database, and at last get the smaller result from database. Don't need to filter result in server.

Comment: @CornelVerster And `$products = $products->whereIn('type', $request->types)->where('active', 1)->get()` you can set the result to $products.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the get method in products.

```
$products = Product::whereIn('type', $request->types)->where('active', 1)->get();
```